Quantum scattering of particles from an object of size $D$
As a rule of thumb, one assumes that the scattering of a monoenergetic beam of quantum particles from another object of spatial size (say, diameter) $D$, takes place when $\lambda\sim D$, where $\lambda=h/p$ is the de Broglie wavelength of the particle. Can we justify this condition from rigorous non-relativistic quantum scattering theory?
